# Document upload not working in Couchbase with couchbase java client implementation

Tags: java, docker-compose, couchbase

Below is the requirement and issues faced.

Requirement: The document/s should be uploaded to couchbase bucket on the launch of Docker. These document/s could be read by another Storm topology.

Solution tried :

1] cbdocloader with cbdocloader we were able to upload multiple documents to bucket but those were not readable by Storm. + the behavior was inconsistent ,sometimes worked ,sometimes not.

```
2423 [main] WARN n.s.m.t.SerializingTranscoder - Failed to decompress data
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165) ~
[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79) ~
[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91) ~
[?:1.8.0_144]
at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.decompress(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:181) [storm-enrichment-5.4.2-100007-jar-with-dependencies.jar:5.4.2-100007]
```

2] Implemented Couchbase java client  1.x to upload documents the issues faced were inconsistent as sometimes it used to upload the document and sometimes not . At max only 2 documents were uploaded.

```
com.couchbase.client.vbucket.config.ConfigParsingException: Number of vBuckets must be a power of two, > 0 and <= 65536 (got 0)
at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.config.DefaultConfigFactory.parseCouchbaseBucketJSON(DefaultConfigFactory.java:215)
at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.config.DefaultConfigFactory.parseJSON(DefaultConfigFactory.java:127)
```

3] Implemented Couchbase java client  2.x to upload documents

On docker launch , enable to connect to localhost :8091  ,

```
com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel $AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:11210
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:225)
at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
```

Comment: Could you post your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml? Witch OS your are using?

Answer (score 0):

With 1.x , tried uploading all the docuements inside a folder in a single connection to Couchbase and the in the end called shutdown.

opening a connection and closing are heavy opearations and may cause issues.